# JavaScript: save a background image to the user's disk

Tags: javascript, html

I have this HTML element:

```
<div style='background-image: url("data:image/png; base64, ENCODEDPNGBYTEDATA")' />
```

How can i extract the image right from the background-image property and show a save file dialog to allow the user to save an image file on his disk?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just reference the file? Base64 encoding increases the file size by 50% anyways.

Comment: The image is not stored on the server side, it is generated and sended to a client, which sees it on some element and can download it, if he want.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
// Get the image id, style and the url from it
var img = document.getElementById('testdiv'),
  style = img.currentStyle || window.getComputedStyle(img, false),
  bi = style.backgroundImage.slice(4, -1).replace(/"/g, "");

// Display the url to the user
console.log('Image URL: ' + bi);

<div id="testdiv" style="background-image:url('http://placehold.it/200x200');"></div>
```

on this case you get the url from your imagen with this you can add a link for donwload your image
example

```
<a href="/path/to/image.png" download="AwesomeImage.png">
```

Comment: that do not work if the source is encoded with data:image/svg